# why am I getting '1' as last element of the array at index arr[2] after shifting the elements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

why am I getting '1' as last output at index arr[2] after shifting the elements

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void shifting(int* arr)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array[n] = { 5, 2, 3 };
    shifting(array);       //shifting the elements to left side 
    return 0;
}
```

output:
2
3
1

Comment: In this line: `arr[i] = arr[i + 1];` you have UB  when `i` is 2 (in the last iteration).

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior. You read one element beyond the end of the array. The program should crash, but it can return the random value that is in that location.
Also learn to use std::array or std::vector instead of refering to arrays by a pointer to the first element (that's a kind of "C" legacy). And do not use "using namespace  std;"

Comment: @OP After shifting, what is the expected output for the last value?  You never mentioned what you *should* be getting -- instead you only posted what you *are* getting.  Right now, it isn't clear what your expected output should be.'

Comment: If your entire question is "why am I getting 1", the entire answer is that you are getting undefined behavior for reading past the end of an array.  It is entirely undefined what you will get from this program.

Comment: What I get is: **<source>:20:15: error: 'n' was not declared in this scope** https://godbolt.org/z/1xceWeaqG

Comment: `shifting` should take a `std::span`, `std:array` or `std::vector`. And use `at` to get out-of-bounds exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are shifting is wrong. The proper way to do it is to store the value in a temp element and then shift.

For eg.

```
temp=arr[0]
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
    }
```

Here add arr[2]=temp

Comment: This is only a part of the answer. The code still has Undefined Behaviour in the last iteration and `temp` is unused.

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing an out of bounds array on line

> arr[i] = arr[i + 1];

when `i=2` the right hand side evaluates to arr[3], which is out of bounds.

This generates undefined, buggy behavior. This has already been answered much better by people at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239938/accessing-an-array-out-of-bounds-gives-no-error-why)

Answer (score 0):

This is called undefined behavior in C++, the way you are shifting is indexing the array out of bounds, meaning that you are trying to access an element that doesn't exist in the array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the last value to be. If you want the array to output 2, 3, 5:

- store the first element(arr[0]) in a temp variable
- iterate through the array just like you did but stop at the (n-1)th element i.e., (i < n-1)
- then store the temp value in arr[n-1].